# looping movieclip on next click

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, movieclip

can you help me.. i want to loop this movieclip in the next click.. but i can't 
or i must make a new movieclip to get next click?

---

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

opo.visible = false;
var ae = true;
var ono : int = 1;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, press)
function press(event:MouseEvent):void{
    opo.visible = true;
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,vib)
function vib (e:Event):void{
    if(ae){
    opo.z = opo.z - ono
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, peneg)
function peneg (event:MouseEvent):void{
    ae = false;
}
```

---

help me please :)

Comment: Please clarify. 1). Is this MovieClip a class you wrote, or timeline code?  2). There is no play/stop command here, nor a programmatic loop such as for/while/do; what do you mean by "loop"? 3). Explain the issue you're encountering that's preventing you from doing your "loop".  Alternatively, perhaps you could explain what it is you're trying to do.  The solution might not be what you imagine.

Comment: have you tried `gotoAndPlay(1)` inside the press method?  You're question is very unclear.